# Im tried to try many solution to solve HTTP status code must be integer in django when pass varible by render

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Dears
I have 3 models and I want to pass them to the template by render  since when I put the third array I get the error : HTTP status code must be an integer

My model is

```
class Dashwidget(models.Model):
    Wname=models.charfield(max_lenght=200)
    Categoryw=models.ForeignKey(category,related-name='categorydashboard',one_delete=models.CASCADE)
    preserve_default=false,
    sql_query=models.TextField('sql',blank=False)
```

My View is

```
def dashbaord(request):
    domain_list=domain.objects.all()
    Context={'domain_list', domain_list}
    Category_list= Category.objects.all()
    Contextcategory={'Category_list', Category_list}
    Widget_list=Dashwidget.objects.all()
    Contextwidget={'Widget_list', Widget_list}
    return render(request,"Dashboard.html",Context,Contextcategory,Contextwidget)
```

Comment: Colud you please send exact code to me im newbie in django

Comment: Changed my comment into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add all of your querysets to `Context` and not pass them as separate arguments to `render`. The 5th argument to `render` is the HTTP status code of the response and you are passing a dictionary

```
def dashbaord(request):
    domain_list=domain.objects.all()
    Category_list= Category.objects.all()
    Widget_list=Dashwidget.objects.all()
    return render(request, "Dashboard.html", {
        'domain_list': domain_list,
        'Category_list': Category_list,
        'Widget_list': Widget_list
    })
```

Comment: Dear now i get error context must be a dict rather than set

Comment: Sorry, copied your code as I thought they were dictionaries but they were sets. Updated the answer